# null when I try to call username

Tags: authentication, null

I am trying to make something with sessions. I have a login form which works well with MySQL database. Now I would like to have a set Session, where it says "Hello B85417" (My username). Everytime I log in I get a this message:

You put in the correct information Hellonull.

Kan anyone see what is wrong here? Best Regards from Mads
index.jsp:

```
<form action="LoginServlet">

            Please enter your username         
            <input type="text" name="un"/><br>        

            Please enter your password
            <input type="text" name="pw"/>

            <input type="submit" value="submit">            
</form>
```

from the login form you are coming to this page:

userLogged.jsp:

```
<body>

     Hello <%= session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser") %>
```

The servlet who configures the login looks like this:

```
    package ExamplePackage;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;



public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                       throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

        try {       

            UserBean user = new UserBean();
            user.setUserName(request.getParameter("un"));
            user.setPassword(request.getParameter("pw"));

            user = UserDAO.login(user);

        if (user.isValid()) {

          HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);       
          session.setAttribute("currentSessionUser",user); 
          response.sendRedirect("userLogged.jsp"); //logged-in page  
          RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("PersonalSite.jsp");
          rd.include(request,response);
        }

        else 
          response.sendRedirect("invalidLogin.jsp"); //error page 
        } 


            catch (Throwable theException) {
                System.out.println(theException); 
            }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me.

You should use

```
<%= session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser");%>
```

in the jsp

Request scope will ends in the LoginServlet so it wont available to next jsp. if you call directly userLogged.jsp from index.jsp then it works fine.

OR in the LoggedInServlet
we will have to forward or include the requests to the another jsp rather than redirect.
If you use request Dispatchers for that it will be best as per my knowledge.

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("your_Jsp_name.jsp");
   rd.include(request,response);
```

then only the http request you can get into the another jsp also from your LoginServlet.

OR
you can set these values to the session in the LoginServlet only as follows:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("Your_KEY","Your_Value");
```

make sure to import `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession` in the ServletClass.

Comment: Hello. Thanks a lot for your answer. When I put in the:

<body>
    <%@ page import="ExamplePackage.LoginServlet" %>
 Hello <%= session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser")%>

</body>

in personal site i get this in my browser:
"Hello ExamplePackage.UserBean@7e054643"

Do you have an idea why I do this?

Comment: and also in the userLogged.jsp

Comment: NOTICE: I just edited the servlet and JSP with the new information. But I still get the message "Hello ExamplePackage"

Comment: You dont have to import your servlet in jsp just add the session.getAttribute('currentSessionUser') in jsp that will fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. No matter which JSP page I put it in, I keep getting the error: "Hello ExamplePackage.UserBean@16a6a7d2"

Comment: see you have set the user class to the session so that your getting the user class not the name if you want user name then either you set the user name in session like session.setAttribute('cureentSessionUser',user.getName()); or your get the user object and call the setter methed of name from your jsp from the object.

Comment: we have to add this in each and every jsp where ever is required.